# NullPointerException? Not sure why. LIBGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I keep getting a `NullPointerException` on line 39, which is 
`modelBatch.begin(cam);`

I have no idea as to why it's doing this. If you notice why, please tell me. I've been struggling with this problem all day now. I am new to android development, and am prone to making silly mistakes. Thank you for your help.

```
public class Loading implements Screen {

private boolean AP;
private Chemistry chemistry;
public PerspectiveCamera cam;
public ModelBatch modelBatch;
public Model model;
public ModelInstance instance;
public Lights lights;

public Loading(boolean AP, Chemistry chemistry) {
    this.AP = AP;
    this.chemistry = chemistry;
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    modelBatch.begin(cam);
    modelBatch.render(instance, lights);
    modelBatch.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void show() {
            modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
    lights = new Lights();
    lights.ambientLight.set(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f);
    lights.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f,
            -0.2f));

    cam = new PerspectiveCamera(70, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.position.set(10f, 10f, 10f);
    cam.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
    cam.near = 0.1f;
    cam.far = 300f;
    cam.update();

    ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
    model = modelBuilder.createBox(5f, 5f, 5f,
            new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.GREEN)),
            Usage.Position | Usage.Normal);

    instance = new ModelInstance(model);

}
       ...
}
```

Comment: did you ever instanciate `PerspectiveCamera cam`?

Comment: What do you mean by that. I have cam = new PerspectiveCamera(70, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
I'm following the test examples on GitHub.

Comment: Yes, i see it. But which method is called first? `render(float delta) `or `show()`?

Comment: Haha, you're German aren't you? You said oder instead of or. I'm taking German in school in America. Back on topic, how do I control which method is called first?

Comment: Sorry, my german fault. *g* Possibility: Do `System.out.println` with the respective method name. First printed = first called.

Comment: `modelBatch` must be null. Put a breakpoint on that line and check.

Comment: Show is first. Render is second.

Comment: How would I put a breakpoint there?

Comment: Hmm... `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` correct?

Comment: I think so. I'm following [this.](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/g3d/Basic3DTest.java)

Comment: `yourScreen.show()` will get called whenever you call `Game.setScreen(yourScreen)` and `yourScreen.render()` will be called repeatedly as long as `yourScreen` is the game's current screen. `modelBatch.begin(cam)` does nothing but set its internal camera to `cam`, so `modelBatch` has to be `null`. Show us how you are creating/setting your screen/game. Also are you sure that line is throwing the exception? Can you include the stacktrace?

Comment: Main class: http://pastebin.com/Q9ACiaVM
I'm using an android phone for this, so here's my logcat: http://pastebin.com/Qq093pvE
Also, I thought I should include the android MainActivity: http://pastebin.com/5cCRvXeB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move this to your constructor:

```
        modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
lights = new Lights();
lights.ambientLight.set(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f);
lights.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f,
        -0.2f));

cam = new PerspectiveCamera(70, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
        Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
cam.position.set(10f, 10f, 10f);
cam.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
cam.near = 0.1f;
cam.far = 300f;
cam.update();

ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
model = modelBuilder.createBox(5f, 5f, 5f,
        new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.GREEN)),
        Usage.Position | Usage.Normal);

instance = new ModelInstance(model);
```

like:

```
public Loading(boolean AP, Chemistry chemistry) {
    this.AP = AP;
    this.chemistry = chemistry;
    //here
}
```

Comment: WOW. That works. Should I just leave the show() method empty then?

Comment: Just be careful not to reuse the same Loading screen if you dispose of any resources in the `dispose()` method since you are no longer creating them when the screen is shown.

Comment: yes, usually you don't use the show method.
Loading -> MainMenu -> Game. Only one instance at the time, and if you want to keep loading screen instance instead of making another one each "resume", just keep it in a field.

Comment: If you do, then it will get called twice. Once when the object is created and again when you call `game.setScreen()`

Comment: Is there any way I could make this work similarly to how it normally does. Why do I have to put everything in the constructor?